# Ionic Serve Work works But Run android Fails

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have created an ionic app and added the android **plaform** but when I run the command

```
ionic cordova run android
```

it it does not run even though ionic serve --lab works,it gives me the following error

> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Emmanuel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
>           studio
>   Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
>    (node:19600) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise          rejection  (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

Comment: Try to run a sample project on Android Studio and see if works.

Answer (score 2):

This basically means that you don't have **gradle** or it's badly configured.

#### In windows

1. download [gradle](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip)
2. Create a new directory C:\Gradle with File Explorer & drag the content folder gradle-4.6 to your newly created C:\Gradle folder.
3. In File Explorer right-click on the This PC (or Computer) icon, then click **Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environmental Variables**.
   Under System Variables select Path, then click Edit. Add an entry for **C:\Gradle\gradle-4.6\bin**. Click OK to save.
4. Verify your installation `$ gradle -v`

#### In Debian/Ubuntu

1. `$ wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip`
2. Create a directory for the Gradle installation.  $ sudo mkdir /opt/gradle
3. Extract the downloaded archive to the newly created directory.
   $ sudo unzip -d /opt/gradle gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip
4. Configure the PATH environment variable so that the gradle executable can be directly executed anywhere on the system.
   $ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-3.4.1/bin
5. Run the following command to check if the Gradle install was
   successful   $ gradle -v

Comment: thanks @Melchia, that is eaxactly what the problem was, plus I had to download sdk tools and extract in the required folder